# Configuring yaml workflow for typescript express server to cloud run?

Tags: node.js, typescript, docker, yaml, google-cloud-run

Hello I have a typescript server with a build script that looks like

```
    "`build": "rm -rf build && tsc && cp package*.json build && cp Dockerfile build && npm ci --prefix build --production"`
```

This creates a new build directory and copies the Dockerfile to the build directory, so the deployed application should be run on the build directory.

I want to automate deployment to Cloud Run using github workflows so I created a .yaml file but during the run portion I am confused how I can build the docker image and push it from my build directory

```
- name: Enable the necessary APIs and enable docker auth
  run: |-
    gcloud services enable containerregistry.googleapis.com
    gcloud services enable run.googleapis.com
    gcloud --quiet auth configure-docker
- name: Build and tag image
  run: |-
    docker build . --tag "gcr.io/$CLOUD_RUN_PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME:$GITHUB_SHA"
- name: Push image to GCR
  run: |-
    docker push gcr.io/$CLOUD_RUN_PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME:$GITHUB_SHA
```

My question is how can I insure to run the docker commands from the build directory ?

Answer (score 2):

On the `docker build` command, replace the `.` with `build/`.

Here's a a full reference of an example workflow including the step to deploy the image to Cloud Run.

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - example-build-deploy

name: Build and Deploy a Container
env:
  PROJECT_ID: ${{ secrets.GCP_PROJECT }}
  SERVICE: hello-cloud-run
  REGION: us-central1

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Setup Cloud SDK
      uses: google-github-actions/setup-gcloud@v0
      with:
        project_id: ${{ env.PROJECT_ID }}
        service_account_key: ${{ secrets.GCP_SA_KEY }}
        export_default_credentials: true  # Set to true to authenticate the Cloud Run action

    - name: Authorize Docker push
      run: gcloud auth configure-docker

    - name: Build and Push Container
      run: |-
        docker build  -t gcr.io/$CLOUD_RUN_PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME:$GITHUB_SHA build/
        docker push gcr.io/$CLOUD_RUN_PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME:$GITHUB_SHA

    - name: Deploy to Cloud Run
      id: deploy
      uses: google-github-actions/deploy-cloudrun@v0
      with:
        service: ${{ env.SERVICE }}
        image: gcr.io/$CLOUD_RUN_PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME:$GITHUB_SHA
        region: ${{ env.REGION }}

    - name: Show Output
      run: echo ${{ steps.deploy.outputs.url }}
```

You may also check the full Github repository sample [here](https://github.com/google-github-actions/deploy-cloudrun/blob/main/.github/workflows/example-workflow.yaml).